# two way binding and validation of drop down list in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to do two way binding in angular with a drop down list. I also want to make the form invalid if not any value is selected.

Below is my code.

```
<form clas="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="submit(frm)" #frm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 selectBox" >Type</label>
        <!--<select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="type" ngModel>
            <option value="select" >Select</option>
            <option value="Free" >Free</option>
            <option value="Paid" >Paid</option>
        </select>-->
            <select name="type"  class="form-control col-sm-4" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue.value" #selects="ngModel" (change)="selection($event)" required>
                <option *ngFor="let item of sel" [value]="item.value" [disabled]="item.type=='Select'">{{item.type}}</option>
        </select>
        <div *ngIf="selects.invalid">
            select your type
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

component file is

```
import { Component}  from '@angular/core';
import { colorPreference } from '../colorPreference';
import {NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
    templateUrl:'./test.html',
    styleUrls:['./test.scss']
})
export class testComponent{
    sel=[{type:'Select',value:''},{type:'Free',value:'Free'},{type:'Paid',value:'Paid'}];
    selectedValue=this.sel[0];
    constructor(private colorService:colorPreference)
    {

    }
    
    submit(form:NgForm) {
        console.log(form.value);
    }
    selection(event:any) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
            this.selectedValue=null;
            for(var i=0;i<this.sel.length;i++)
            {
                console.log(this.sel[i].type+" value is "+this.sel[i].value);
                if(this.sel[i].value==event) {
                    this.selectedValue=this.sel[i];
                }
            }
    }
}
```

but when i change the drop down list value it shows an error

```
test.html:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Your problem is here `if(this.sel[i].value==event)` Why do you check it with `event` while it should be `event.target.value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why you are getting this error becasue:

> test.html:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Whne you change the drop down value it pass value to the `ngModel` but , in the `ngModel` you are having this `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue.value"`

---

**Solution :**

Change this :

`selectedValue=this.sel[0];` to `selectedValue=this.sel[0].value;`

And

`[(ngModel)]="selectedValue.value"` to `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"`